# Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been blocked by CORS policy Flask API + NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flask, cors, flask-cors

I have a problem between frontend backend and Flask API.

To execute my project I do `npm start. This will run the ReactJs frontend dev server on port 3000.

In package.json

I added the following "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",

Next, I do

cd backend && python server.py after activating my venv

This will run the Flask API on port 5000

The Flask API has this route

```
from flask_cors import cross_origin
# File download Link
@app.route('/filePath', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def get_path():
    data = request.get_json()["path"]
    storage.child(f"files/{data}").download(f"files/Resume.pdf")
    return "Success.."
```

Finally, in another shell I do

cd backend && node server.js running on port 8080

Which has the following post

```
app.post('/insert', async (req, response) => {
    const mobile_number = req.body.college_name
    const name = req.body.college_name
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/details').then(async (res) => {
        const recruit = new RecruitModel({
            mobile_number:res.data.mobile_number, name:res.data.name,
            });
        await recruit.save()
        response.send("inserted data")
      });
});
```

Here is where the error happens in the frontend.

```
const uploadFiles = (file) => {
      //
      if (!file) return;
      if (!initialData) return null;
      const storageRef = ref(storage, files/${file.name});
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
  
      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const prog = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );
          setProgress(prog);
        },
        (error) => console.log(error),
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async () => {
            console.log(file.name);
            await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/filePath', {
              'path': file.name
            }).then(() => console.log(file.name));
            update();
          });
        }
      );
    };
```

In await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/filePath' I'm assuming.

I get the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/insert' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
'http://localhost:5000' that is not equal to the supplied origin

I thought using flask-cors would fix this so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

I'm really struggling on this error, Any suggestions please?